# Android navigation drawer set clickable area only to list items

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I am using a `NavigationDrawer` in my application and I am loading in the drawer a `ListView`. When the drawer is opened, it covers almost half of an `Activity` which contains also a `ListView`.

The problem that I face is that if I tap on the drawer(not on an item contained in the drawer), a `ListView` item from my `Activity` gets the click event and then starts an activity associated with that list item.

Is it possible to restrict the clickable area of the drawer only to the list items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your drawer layout is more complex than just a simple `ListView`, if you have place to tap on the drawer. 
In that case, you could simple specify
`android:clickable="true"` for your top drawer layout (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or whatever you use).